# SPI with 2 ADCs (ADS1299) whilst synchronized

Tags: arduino, adc, spi

I am using 2 ADCs in the following manner:

[image]

I am using the SPI comm pins, with only CS differing for each chip. The ADC also has an internal oscillator, and on my device 1, I have clk_sel pin tied to DVDD (which means the internal oscillator is activated, [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ads1299.pdf)) and on device 2 I have it tied to ground (meaning it requires an external clock). On device 1, I have written 0b11110110 to the CONFIG1 register, which connects the CLK pin on the chip to the internal oscillator.

So with device 1 having an internal oscillator via tying CLK_SEL pin to DVDD, and outputting it via the CLK pin through modifying register CONFIG1, and device 2 having CLK_SEL tied to ground and its CLK pin connected to device 1's CLK pin, I am just trying to read the registers from device 2.

I have the following process in place:

- turning device 1 CS low;
- modifying CONFIG1 so CLK is connected to device 1's oscillator;
- turning device 1 CS high;
- turning device 2 CS low;
- reading registers.

For some reason I am getting random values, meaning it is not reading the registers properly. is there anything obvious I am missing? I double and tripled checked the connection between the comms pins and the chip pins but all seems OK.

Comment: The datasheet suggests to tie CLKSEL pin to VDD or GND through 10k (min) resistors. It's still worth to try if you tied directly.

Comment: @RohatKılıç That's how I did it.

Comment: Can you verify that ADC1 actually outputs the CLK signal?

Comment: @LiorBilia It is giving out a clock signal at 1.75 MHz, which is below the spec of 2 MHz in the datasheet, but still within the range for the required frequency of a master clock